# selected checkbox remain checked/unchecked after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have this simple checkbox.

My problem is, if I select any of the checkbox, it should remain checked after form submission.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="make-up"> Make-up <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="massage"> massage <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="haircut"> Haircut <br>
```

I tried this code from radio button hoping to work but I failed.

```
<?php if (isset($services) && $services=="make-up") echo "checked";?>
```

I learned that it will work using localstorage.. however all the example I saw is very complicated.

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use AJAX.

Comment: Where have you placed the php code?

Comment: inside the input sir

Comment: your action url is same as current url ?

Comment: yes sir, its in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are wanting to use a checkbox, you may want to array the input name(s):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="make-up"> Make-up <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="massage"> massage <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="haircut"> Haircut <br>
```

combined with a function like:

```
<?php 
function isChecked($value)
    {
        return (!empty($_REQUEST['services']) && in_array($value,$_REQUEST['services']));
    }
```

To end up with something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="make-up"<?php if(isChecked('make-up')) echo ' checked' ?>> Make-up <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="massage"<?php if(isChecked('massage')) echo ' checked' ?>> massage <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="haircut"<?php if(isChecked('haircut')) echo ' checked' ?>> Haircut <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it checked by:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="make-up" 
<?php if (isset($_REQUEST['services']) && in_array("make-up",$_REQUEST['services'])) echo "checked";?>> Make-up <br>
```

Same for the other fields .

This will make it checked if posted value is same as that of checkbox value.

Answer (score 0):

you can't  access `services as $services` you should access from `REQUEST` like this `$_REQUEST['services']` and assign to variable like this `$services=$_REQUEST['services'];`

**HTML :**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="make-up" <?php if(isset($services) && $services=="make-up"){ echo "checked"; }  ?> > Make-up <br>

<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="massage" <?php if(isset($services) && $services=="massage"){ echo "checked"; }  ?> > massage <br>

<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="haircut" <?php if(isset($services) && $services=="haircut"){ echo "checked"; }  ?> > Haircut <br>
```